# Efficient way to read+write data from CouchDB

Tags: couchdb

I am implementing an application that includes a user who logs in to access a document stored in a hosted CouchDB store. The user provides their credentials to the app, and once the app authenticates them, the app then has two jobs:

1. Get the Document ID associated with that user's data
2. Update the "lastOpened" value stored in that document

I am having to do those two things in a way that seems rather inefficient: I read a View which maps the app's user identifier (their email address in this case) to their Document ID. Once I have the Document ID (and have added it to the session for later use) I then have to request the Document, uptick the "lastOpened" value, then save the Document back to the store.

That looks like 3 trips to the database to me: 1. Get the Document ID from the View, 2. Get the Document, using that ID, 3. Save the updated Document.

Is there anyway to reduce that work to fewer database trips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> That looks like 3 trips to the database to me: 1. Get the Document ID from the View, 2. Get the Document, using that ID, 3. Save the updated Document.
>
> Is there anyway to reduce that work to fewer database trips?

You can fetch document from a view by adding "?include_docs=true" query parameter in request. So two steps instead of three.

Comment: Accepted this answer due to its simplicity. Two steps is reasonable: one to get the document and one to store the update.  I don't have the option of using the user's login ID as the document ID, so while using an update handler could theoretically reduce the number of steps down to one, it can't be applied in this case.

Answer (score 3):

If you can change the document structure, you could use the user's login name as the document ID. That way, you don't have to use a view. Using [update handlers](https://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers), you could even do all the work in one request.